# How to add Yandex map in android?

Tags: java, android, yandex

I tried to add the Yandex map in my android application 
and I did all things as shown [here](https://tech.yandex.com/maps/doc/mapkit/3.x/concepts/android/quickstart-docpage/)

I added `implementation 'com.yandex.android:mapkit:3.0.0'` in to dependencies and

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://maven.google.com/"
    }
}
```

and finally `mavenCentral()` into repositories

Everything was right when I sync but when I rebuilt the app I got

> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to
>   process
>   D:\android\SD_Delivery\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\21.jar
>   com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while
>   dexing.    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -214748364

Where did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Adding: app level of build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
  ...
  implementation 'com.yandex.android:mapkit:3.0.0'
}
```

For solve Dex problem [try it](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2384#issuecomment-361920773)

Answer (score 0):

here said that updating to android studio 3.2 must solve the problem: https://github.com/yandex/mapkit-android-demo/issues/2